# duplicate loops in C

Tags: c, loops

Why are there duplicated values present? It should have looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAG13.jpg) but instead the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BQuo.jpg). I wanted to find a pair of 2d array that sums up to the inputted number.

here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int num[3][4] = {5, -1, 17, 8, 4, 18, -3, 15, 26, 6, -6, 10};
  int checker, val;

  printf("Enter integer to check: ");
  scanf("%d", &checker);
  printf("The pair of integers that add to %d are\n", checker);

  for (size_t value = 0; value < 12; value++) {
    for (size_t value1 = 0; value1 < 12; value1++) {
      for (size_t value2 = 0; value2 < 12; value2++) {
        for (size_t value3 = value2 + 1; value3 < 12; value3++) {
          val = num[value][value1] + num[value2][value3];
          if (val == checker) {
            printf("[%d,%d],", num[value][value1], num[value2][value3]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You go out of bounds of your arrays, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Could you specify where I did go out of bounds in my array? I did specify in the loop the number of arrays which is 12. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You have an array `num` with three elements. You iterate over 12 elements on that array. You will in fact use elements up to `num[11][11]`.

Comment: Valgrind and address sanitizer are your friends.

Comment: Please, include your outputs (expected and actual) as text rather than images.

Comment: "I did specify in the loop the number of arrays which is 12." --> Why 12 and not 3, 4: `for (size_t value = 0; value < 3; value++) {  for (size_t value1 = 0; value1 < 4; value1++) {`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are doing:

```
printf("[%d,%d],", num[value][value1], num[value2][value3]);
```

I propose you to do:

```
printf("value=[%d], value1=[%d], value2=[%d], value3=[%d], [%d,%d],", 
value, value1, value2, value3,
num[value][value1], num[value2][value3]);
```

So, not only print the matrix values, but also the indices. You'll see what's happening.

Comment: I see this is so helpful! Cheers.

Comment: I had seen the problem is in the indices, but instead of doing the whole analysis, I thought of giving you the opportunity to find this out yourself. I'm glad you like it :-)